# MySQL Query Database Attendance get in/out

Tags: php, mysql, ms-access, migrate

I have database Microsoft Access

Table **CHECKTIME**

```
USERID    CHEKTIME
1         2015-06-21 07:34:00
1         2015-06-21 07:50:00
1         2015-06-21 16:00:00
1         2015-06-21 16:48:00
2         2015-06-21 07:08:00
2         2015-06-21 13:48:00
2         2015-06-21 17:08:00
3         ....................
```

I want to transfer data into MySQL query with results:

```
userId    colDate         colIn          colOut
1         2015-06-21      07:34:00       16:48:00
2         2015-06-21      07:08:00       17:08:00
3         ..........      ........       ........
```

Please help me

this query makes me stuck for final test

why data can't insert into PHPMyAdmin? or ms access can't declare MIN and MAX query? How about this function and query:

```
public function getPresensi(){


$dbName = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/presensi-app/assets/database/upj.mdb";
$user = "";
$password = "";


$conn = odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=$dbName", $user, $password);

$qry = "SELECT USERID as id, CHECKTIME as check, min(CHECKTIME) as masuk, max(CHECKTIME) as keluar FROM CHECKINOUT group by USERID,date(CHECKTIME)";

$result = odbc_exec($conn,$qry);

while ($data[] = odbc_fetch_array($result));

odbc_free_result($result);

odbc_close($conn);

$tbl = 'tb_kehadiran';
$db_mysql = $this->load->database('default',TRUE);
$db_mysql->trans_start();
$db_mysql->truncate($tbl);
foreach($data as $k => $v){

    $data_mysql = array(

        'colUserID' => $v['id'],
        'colDate' => $v['check'],
        'colJamMasuk' => $v['masuk'],
        'colJamKeluar' => $v['keluar'],

    );
    if($data_mysql != null){
    $db_mysql->insert($tbl, $data_mysql);
    }

    }

    $db_mysql->trans_complete();
    $db_mysql->close();


}
```

Comment: you should explain a bit more, what are the requirements for selecting the certain times as in or out? Is it always the first one and the last one, regardless of what time it is? I.E. someone forgot to check in in the morning and when checking out accidentally checks out 2 times, resulting in 2 time in the db.

Comment: don't forget to add what you already tried yourself.

Comment: the database is not the explanation of the data check in or out. but the data will record each person check in at any time. if the person is only one check-in, Colin and colout will be the same. example: userID, colDate, Colin, colout ->1, 2015-08-21, 08:00:00, 08:00:00

Comment: SELECT USERID as id, CHECKTIME as date, MIN(CHECKTIME) as colIn, MAX(CHECKTIME) as colOut FROM CHCKINOUT

Comment: You have multiple problems with your php code. Test the query first in phpmyadmin and comment if that is the result you want, then we can work on the php

Comment: the query for get data from ms access and the php to import result query to phpmyadmin. i stuck for this code

Comment: you will not be able to test the query with phpmyadmin, because you're getting the data out of MS-Access. try the query in ms-access first and see if you get results. then we have to rewrite you code if the results are correct, because you code has many errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on you're comment, try this:

```
SELECT USERID as id, CHEKTIME as date, MIN(CHEKTIME) as colIn, MAX(CHEKTIME) as colOut FROM timetable group by userid,date(chektime)
```

When using **max** and **min** to get results, you'll only get one result if you're not using the grouping by option. Add the grouping by to group by user and date (so you'll also get more then one date, for each user)

you can check it out here [at sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c5062/15)

and to change the date format use:

```
date_format(CHEKTIME,'%y-%m-%d') as date
```

**You're question change a lot since I started** 
This is a wrap up of what problems I've seen so far with you post/code.

1. you don't declare you're mysql connection
2. you free result and close connecting to ms-access before doing anything with the data
3. you're using the deprecated mysql instead of mysqli
4. you haven't tested if you're query return results (with both MS-Access as reference or your code)

Take on step at a time and start debugging what you have/don't have.

Steps to resolve:

1. Test query in MS-Access and see if you have results, fix if no result
2. Change your code to print the result to screen before doing anything else
3. create another connection to mysql (not MS-Access)

**to display all errors add the following right after opening php**

```
 ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
 ini_set('log_errors', 1); 
 ini_set('error_log', dirname(__FILE__) . '/error_log.txt'); 
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 $error='';
```

**Update 2:**
The ms-access query should be:

```
SELECT Checktime.USERID, DateValue([CHEKTIME]) AS [Day], Min(TimeValue([CHEKTIME])) AS [In], Max(TimeValue([CHEKTIME])) AS Out FROM Checktime GROUP BY Checktime.USERID, DateValue([CHEKTIME]);
```

Comment: in my PHPMyAdmin still the data is NULL

Comment: I don't think you tried it in your db admin (PHPMyadmin), but you tested you're code, if you have other problems with your code, then you won't get the results, try it in phpmyadmin (not your php code) and see if you get results. As you can see in sqlfiddle it works correctly

Comment: as you're not responding fast enough, I will go to bed now. I will see if you fixed anything in the morning

Comment: i use php codeigniter $db_mysql = $this->load->database('default',TRUE); is for connect to mysql database

Comment: cant use group by date(checktime). thamks for respond and please if youre free help me

Comment: try `SELECT Checktime.USERID, DateValue([CHEKTIME]) AS [Day], Min(TimeValue([CHEKTIME])) AS [In], Max(TimeValue([CHEKTIME])) AS Out
FROM Checktime
GROUP BY Checktime.USERID, DateValue([CHEKTIME]);`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT checktime.userid, 
       Date([chektime])    AS Day, 
       Min(Time(chektime)) AS CheckIn, 
       Max(Time(chektime)) AS CheckOut 
FROM   checktime 
GROUP  BY checktime.userid, 
          Date([chektime]);
```